# Replacing Color in element.style with JavaScript, Jquery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there are a few examples in the community where folks have been able to accomplish this, but I'm struggling with my particular example.

I have a script that's adding a widget on my site, and it's setting the color in `element.style` with the HTML to `color: rgb(0, 0, 0);`, I'd like it to be `white`.

```
element.style {
    background-color: rgb(123, 104, 238);
    height: 44px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

And here's where it's set in the HTML

```
<button
  type="button"
  id="ada-chat-button"
  class="button--text button-v2 button--appear"
  aria-label="Chat with bot"
  title="Chat with bot"
  style="
    background-color: rgb(123, 104, 238);
    height: 44px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  "
>
</button>
```

Thank you so much in advance for any direction!!

Comment: `background-color` is the color of the button, `color` is the font color.  White is `rgb(255, 255,255)` or you can directly use `white`

Comment: I've tried setting it with CSS to override how it's set in `element.style` with `.button--text: white` and `.button--text: white !important` but the style isn't being overwritten. I've also tried with JS and Jq but I haven't been successful yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute always takes precedence over css rules because it is applied directly to the element.

If you want to modify one of the values of a style attribute, you can do it with javascript.

Below is an example with jQuery.

```js
$('#ada-chat-button').css({ "color": 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button
  type="button"
  id="ada-chat-button"
  class="button--text button-v2 button--appear"
  aria-label="Chat with bot"
  title="Chat with bot"
  style="
    background-color: rgb(123, 104, 238);
    height: 44px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  "
>Test
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about how style settings are made.  For a simple case you can do it all in the .html file

```html
<body style="background-color: gray;">

  <button
    type="button"
    id="ada-chat-button"
    class="button--text button-v2 button--appear"
    aria-label="Chat with bot"
    title="Chat with bot"
    style="
      background-color: rgb(123, 104, 238);
      height: 44px;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    "
  >The Button
  </button>
  
</body>
```

Try running the code snippet above and you will see, I set `background-color` style property of `body` to gray, `background-color` of `button` to `rgb(123, 104, 238)` and `color` to `rgb(0,0,0)` (which is black).  Now if you change `color` of `button` to `white` or `rgb(255,255,255)` which are the same thing, it will make the font color white.  Try playing around with the above code snippet.

Now if you have a larger project where you want to specify styles separately, you create a separate `.css` file, and it would look like this...

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

button#ada-chat-button {
  background-color: rgb(123, 104, 238);
  height: 44px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button
    type="button"
    id="ada-chat-button"
    class="button--text button-v2 button--appear"
    aria-label="Chat with bot"
    title="Chat with bot"
  >The Button
  </button>
  
</body>
```

The above snippet does the same thing but the styles are set separately in a CSS file.  The "button#ada-chat-button" specifies that the style we are setting only applies to the `button` component with `id=ada-chat-button`. (# specifies id see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).  Alternatively we could have specified by class.  `button.button-v2 {...}` would mean the style applies to every `button` with class `button-v2`.  In your case, you have set the button to have classes `button-v2`, `button--text`, and `button--appear`, which I presume have some meaning in whatever css framework you are using.